# Update a record in mongodb with php

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to update a record and I have already known its _id in mongodb. I followed this :[MongoDB $set not updating record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297495/mongodb-set-not-updating-record)

```
$idVal ="some value";

$new_data =array('$set'=> array("Domain"=>$domain), 
array("author"=>$author),array("title"=>$title));

$collectionList->update(array("_id"=>$idVal), $new_data);
```

The error message is error message127.0.0.1:27017: Unknown modifier: 0

What is wrong with my query? thank you in advance!

Comment: Which Mongo library you are using.?

Comment: $idVal="some Value" ?? Set "$idVal=123456";//any number. and then try

Answer (score 0):

Set $idVal with any number and try..

Example:

```
$idVal =123456;

$new_data =array('$set'=> array("Domain"=>$domain), 
array("author"=>$author),array("title"=>$title));

$collectionList->update(array("_id"=>$idVal), $new_data);
```

Comment: tried the orignial id was 54d5a04a7fba9ad0788b4568, I just did not put it there

Answer (score 0):

You specified wrong update data. If you take a closer look at `$new_data` array, you will notice that it is an array with 3 keys:

```
$new_data = array(
    '$set' => array("Domain"=>$domain),
    0 => array("author"=>$author),
    1 => array("title"=>$title)
);
```

That's why you've got an error *"Unknown modifier: 0"*, because 0 is not a mongodb update operator.

In your case `$new_data` array should be:

```
$new_data = array(
    '$set' => array(
        "Domain"=>$domain, 
        "author"=>$author,
        "title"=>$title
    )
);
```